# Ad Rotator Script - Function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got a script that allows me to add a series of images and links to essentially make an ad rotator. After it is run it sets a time out so that the rotation opart of the script is called at regular intervals so as to change the images and links.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function () {-
alert("LOADED BANNER CODE");
//Global variable that stores advertising banners.
var ads = new Array();

//Function that starts when the page finished loading.

  //Adds information about the new banners.
  ads.push(["http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-7490208-11465196", "http://www.lduhtrp.net/image-7490208-11465196", ""]);
  ads.push(["http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-7490208-11646171", "http://www.ftjcfx.com/image-7490208-11646171", ""]);
  /*
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  ads.push(["", "", ""]);
  */
  //ads.push(["http://w3schools.com/svg/default.asp", "http://adn.impactradius.com/display-ad/378-10418", "SVG"]);

  //Starting rotation with the first banner.
  ad_rotate(0);

function ad_rotate(active){   
  alert("LOADED BANNER ADROTATE CODE");
  //Gets the div that will display banners.
  var ad_element = document.getElementById("ad");

  //Prints a new link with image in advertising box.
  ad_element.innerHTML = "<a href=\""+ads[active][0]+"\"><img src=\""+ads[active][1]+"\" alt=\""+ads[active][2]+"\" title=\""+ads[active][2]+"\" /></a>";

  //Switches to the next banner.
  active++;

  //If the counter has reached the end, it shall start again from zero.
  if(active >= ads.length){
    active = 0;
  }

  //Run the function in 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds).
  setTimeout("ad_rotate("+active+")", 5000);
};
});
```

This works fine on the first run, however the subsequent calls to the 'ad_rotate' function result in an error. Firebug gives:

```
ReferenceError: ad_rotate is not defined
setTimeout("ad_rotate("+active+")", 5000);
```

Any ideas how I can rectify this?

Comment: And where is `active` defined? Nowhere!

Comment: @adaneo Thanks for the constructive input. However, the simple helpful answer posted by Amit some 18 minutes ago has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    ad_rotate(active);
}, 5000);
```

You cannot pass arguments in a settimeout function as it is. You'll need to wrap an anonymous function around it.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
setTimeout(ad_rotate(active), 5000);
```